# error on connection

Tags: asp.net

I am a newbie in using asp.net, I have a problem with this error see link http://i40.tinypic.com/2ikrpi.jpg. The connection is place in a module

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Module connection

Public cn As New SqlConnection("Data     Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\JUSTINE\Documents\Visual Studio     2005\WebSites\ACESCHOOLSUPPLIES\App_Data\ACESCHOOLSUPPLIES.mdf;Integrated     Security=True;User Instance=True")

end module
```

Whenever I get that error I have to change again the sqlconnection so that the connection will work again.I am worrying about this, Iam afraid that this error will appear on the presentation day. Can anyone help me how to fix this?? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From the picture that you've posted that means your sql query wasn't closed yet in the previous query.

But you can try this connection statement declaration

> Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data
>   Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|ACESCHOOLSUPPLIES.mdf';Integrated
>   Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")

If you declare your connection like you did in your form it will get some error when you upload your project to your real windows hosting because it address will redirect to your path that not exist in your hosting disk. Hope this helps you.

Comment: in the link above the connection is close  cmd1.Connection.Close() after the else if

Comment: Have you changed your connection string?

Comment: The time (in seconds) to wait for a connection to open. The default value is 15 seconds.